# find id of the element where the control is dropped using jquery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have got a table with several rows and columns. I have a span in one of the td which I want to drag. I can drag that span and can get the ID of the td where the span lies but I can anyone tell me how can I get the ID of the td where I drop that span. Now I can get the ID in firefox using event.originalTarget.id of the drop event, but unable to get it in IE.

Thanks,

Comment: What Sarfraz means is that whenever someone gives a solution that works for you, click the large checkmark to the left of that solution. It is a small courtesy for the person(s) who took the time to help you. You can also vote an answer up (or down) by clicking the up and down arrows. To review your previous questions, click on your username wherever it appears as a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andy: Thanks but your solution didn't work. I had to used droppable to get the ID of the element where the other element is dropped. btw, I am loving jquery

Answer (score 0):

In IE you should be able to use [`document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536417(VS.85).aspx):

```
element.ondrop = function (e)
{
    var event = e || window.event;
    var droppedOn = event.originalTarget;
    if (!droppedOn)
    {
        var prevDisplay = element.currentStyle.display;
        element.runtimeStyle.display = "none";
        droppedOn = document.getElementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        element.runtimeStyle.display = prevDisplay;
    }

    alert("Dropped on "+droppedOn.id);
    // rest of code...
}
```